# Assign input to submodel -- Convert PyQGIS to ArcGIS Model

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I have a point feature class containing traffic counts for multiple (500) intersections (TrafficCounts) and a polyline feature class containing roads in my county (Roads). I have created a model which:

- snaps TrafficCounts to the appropriate intersection (Snapped),
- buffers the snapped points,
- "hollows out" the buffer (using polygon to lines), and
- computes the intersection between the "hollowed" buffer and the original roads (RoadIntersections).

I need to assign values from the appropriate column of the TrafficCounts attribute table (East, West, North, and South) to a single column in the RoadIntersections attribute table (Count).

[image]

This image shows the attribute table for the center point. I need the four selected points on the circle assigned the values from the attribute table. I have successfully assigned the values with a Python script in QGIS:

```
RoadIntersections.startEditing()
for feat in Snapped.getFeatures(): # Loop over all 500 intersections
    RoadIntersections.selectByExpression("SQL Expression")
    xs, ys = [], []
    for f in RoadIntersections.selectedFeatures():
        xs.append(f.geometry().asPoint().x())
        ys.append(f.geometry().asPoint().y())
    min_x, max_x = min(xs), max(xs)
    min_y, max_y = min(ys), max(ys)
    for f in RoadIntersections.selectedFeatures():
        if min_x == f.geometry().asPoint().x():
            f['count'] = f.attributeMap().get('WEST')
        if max_x == f.geometry().asPoint().x():
            f['count'] = f.attributeMap().get('EAST')
        if min_y == f.geometry().asPoint().y():
            f['count'] = f.attributeMap().get('SOUTH')
        if min_y == f.geometry().asPoint().y():
            f['count'] = f.attributeMap().get('NORTH')
        RoadIntersections.updateFeature(f)
RoadIntersections.commitChanges()
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get started with the ArcPy code to write the loop. I figure this step in the workflow might involve:

- Using the Iterate Feature Selection tool,
- Using the Calculate Field tool
- Specifying an expression to find which RoadIntersection is each extrema.

Update:

Models in ArcGIS Pro can only use [one iterator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/iterators-for-looping.htm#:%7E:text=Only%20one%20iterator%20can%20be,each%20value%20in%20the%20iterator.). I can use the Iterate Row Selection tool to iterate over each of the TrafficCounts. To finish the workflow and assign the correct traffic count to each leg of the intersection, my current code iterates again, this time over each of the RoadIntersections.

Using two iterators in an ArcGIS Pro model requires [adding a submodel to a model](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/add-a-submodel-to-a-model.htm#:%7E:text=Embedding%20a%20model%20tool%20within%20another%20model%20also%20allows%20for%20advanced%20use%20of%20model%20iterators.%20When%20a%20workflow%20requires%20model%20iteration%2C%20the%20specific%20tools%20or%20processes%20that%20need%20to%20be%20run%20more%20than%20once%20must%20be%20separated%20from%20those%20tools%20or%20processes%20that%20only%20need%20to%20be%20run%20once.). I've added the submodel to my main model; however, the submodel does not allow input -- the only option is to add a precondition -- even though I have made the input dataset a parameter in the submodel.